# Add servlet in a clojure ring project

Tags: clojure, servlet-3.0, ring, togglz

I am integrating Togglz library into a Clojure Ring project to support feature toggles and would like to activate the Togglz admin console. According to the [Togglz documentation](https://www.togglz.org/documentation/admin-console.html) it is necessary to add a servlet in the /WEB-INF/web.xml file for projects that don't support Servlet 3.0. I used the :uberjar-merge-with leiningen plugin to merge the file with the Togglz servlet configuration with the web.xml file autogenerated by leiningen. However, this was not sufficient to activate the admin console. 
I could not find much information on how to integrate a servlet from an external library into a Ring application. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: How are you running your application? Are you creating a war and deploying it or something like embedded Jetty?

Comment: Hi Bill, I am using an embedded Jetty.

Comment: If you're using embedded Jetty, (e.g. `lein ring server`, or `lein ring uberjar` to run/build), then AFAIK, you don't get servlet support by default. I'm not sure how to do it, but I'm sure it's possible to enable a 3d party servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but the [lein-servlet](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-servlet) library seems to promise to do exactly that